# IPMI - is it possible to boot a server

Tags: rack, ipmi, wake-on-lan

Is it possible to use IPMI to boot a cPCI server with a backplane? (in a similar fashion to Wake-on-LAN)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IPMI](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/servers/ipmi/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.html) is a network protocol. What it CAN do depends not only on it, but also on how it is implemented.

If you have a BMC that is working even if the computer is off AND it allows to power control the machine - yes. This is standard for any BMC I have ever seen, but some cheap ones out there may not support it.

Often you do not use IPMI even most of the time - you can use a website or some web services to start the machine, using the controller board ([redfish](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redfish_Scalable_Platforms_Management_API))

Comment: hi Tom, I've added a follow up question here if you could kindly have a look: http://serverfault.com/questions/424192/ipmi-cant-ping-or-remotely-connect

Answer (score 3):

If there is power to the BMC, then yes.

Comment: adaptr could you share your expertise on my followup question? http://serverfault.com/questions/424192/ipmi-cant-ping-or-remotely-connect